# Converting object to array javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object like the one below

```
obj= {detailsArray: [{name: 'Bob', age: 45, city: 'newyork'}]}
```

I am trying to convert it into an array something like the below:

```
detailsArray = [{name: 'Bob'}, {age: 45}, {city: 'newyork'}]
```

I have tried doing it with different Object operations but I couldnt complete it. Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: The object you have is not valid syntax

Comment: detailsArray is key and the array is value. Can you please tell where is the syntax problem

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to do this. Why not have it like `detailsArray = [{name: '', age: 45, city: ''}]`

Comment: That's not the problematic part, it's the `[name: 'Bob',` and so on. Arrays don't have named indexes in JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object must be

```
var obj= {detailsArray: {name: 'Bob', age: 45, city: 'newyork'}};
```

OR

```
var obj= {detailsArray: [{name: 'Bob', age: 45, city: 'newyork'}]};
```

If your object is

```
var obj= {detailsArray: {name: 'Bob', age: 45, city: 'newyork'}};
```

```js
var obj= {detailsArray: {name: 'Bob', age: 45, city: 'newyork'}};
var detailsArray= obj.detailsArray;
var arr=[]; 
for (var key in detailsArray) {
    if (detailsArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var obj ={}; obj[key] =detailsArray[key];
        arr.push(obj);
    }
}
detailsArray =arr;
 console.log(detailsArray);
```

if your obj is

```
var obj= {detailsArray: [{name: 'Bob', age: 45, city: 'newyork'}]};
```

```js
var obj= {detailsArray: [{name: 'Bob', age: 45, city: 'newyork'}]};
var detailsArray= obj.detailsArray[0];
var arr=[]; 
for (var key in detailsArray) {
    if (detailsArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var obj ={}; obj[key] =detailsArray[key];
        arr.push(obj);
    }
}
detailsArray =arr;
 console.log(detailsArray);
```